# Overlaying a UIScrollview without cutting off touch events to the scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uiscrollview, siblings

I have a transparent overlay that I'd like to put over a UIScrollview.  I'm adding it as an Imageview sibling view to the scrollview so that it remains stationary while the scrollview subviews move freely underneath.  The problem is that views pass their events to the superview, not the siblings.  IS there a way to pass events from this overlay to the scrollview?  Or can anyone think of a better way to achieve the same effect?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should Just Work, as long as the `UIImageView` has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO`: the superview sends `-hitTests:withEvent:` to its subviews in order, and the `UIImageView` should return `nil`, whereas the `UIScrollView` should return itself (because it has gesture recognizers).

If it's not working for you, the chances are that your view layout is not what you think it is. `UIView` has a useful method called `-recursiveDescription` which you should call on the superview and NSLog the result.

Comment: Haha, case closed.  I thought I tried userInteractionEnabled. Sorry to waste your time.